# Anaconda private token package upload does not work through CI or local

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, gitlab-ci

There is an empty group/organization on our private Anaconda repo, that has a token with scope of 'all' added already. I am a member of the group. The desired path is to have the package be built and uploaded through gitlab ci. The package is properly built under /dist and I have a variable set in the Gitlab repo's project settings with the Anaconda repo's token value. I have the following line in our gitlab-ci.yml under deploy:

```
image: docker.rle.ic.gov/radiance/miniconda3:4.5.11
conda config --add channels our-group-name
anaconda -t $OUR_GROUP_TOKEN upload --force dist/*.tar.gz
```

Output:

```
usage: anaconda [-h] [--disable-ssl-warnings][--show-trackback] [-v] [-q]
                [-V] [-t TOKEN] [-s SITE]
anaconda: error: argument : invalid choice: 'dist/ourtool.tar.gz' (choose from 'auth', 'label', 'channel', 'config', 'copy', 'download', 'groups', 'login', 'logout', 'move', 'notebook', 'package', 'remove', 'search', 'show', 'upload', 'whoami')
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

The same output occurs when I run that command locally in Anaconda 3 console. But I can upload the package correctly if I run the following on my local machine:

```
anaconda --user our-group-name upload --force dist/*.tar.gz
```

It is especially frustrating considering the first code is almost identical to other projects on other groups and they are able to deploy.

Is there something I'm missing? Do I need to do anything special with this group token, either on gitlab ci or on my local machine?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was happening. When I first posted this question, I didn't have a anaconda repo token variable added to my Gitlab CI variables. I did that, and was still having issues. After going back to look at the Gitlab repo token variable a few times, I unchecked Protected and that fixed the problem. I can now seamlessly push code to Gitlab, have it processed, and uploaded to the anaconda repo.